# MYSQL ON UPDATE FROM OTHER DATABASE

Tags: mysql

Im trying to do this:

I have two tables `table_1` and `table_2` and I want to UPDATE a row value in `table_2` every time that `table_1.id = table_2.id`

Actually I have this process on php, but I must run it via cronjob every 5 minutes, but now I need it instantly.

Any idea how I can do this in mysql?

Comment: use a trigger? mysql scheduler?

Comment: im pretty noob in mysql :-/

Comment: Google the things Marc mentioned and stop being noob? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you want, you have to use trigger. Triggers are queries that execute automatically when it meet the condition. When creating a Trigger, you can choose when it will be trigerred. Here are all the possibility :

- Before/After Insert
- Before/After Delete
- Before/After Update

The query is going to execute that condition is meet.
In your trigger statement, you can use OLD and NEW as reference of the new or old element in your table. As documentation says :

> In an INSERT trigger, only NEW.col_name can be used; there is no old
>   row. In a DELETE trigger, only OLD.col_name can be used; there is no
>   new row. In an UPDATE trigger, you can use OLD.col_name to refer to
>   the columns of a row before it is updated and NEW.col_name to refer to
>   the columns of the row after it is updated.

You can also use the BEGIN...END. I dont have mysql on my current computer, but I think the syntax of the right query should be close to this :

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER table_2_insertTrigger AFTER INSERT ON table_2 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE numberOfRow INT;
    SET numberOfRow = (select count(*) from table_1 where table_1.id = NEW.id);
    IF numberOfRow > 0 THEN
      UPDATE table_1 set name = NEW.name where id = NEW.id;
    END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

If you want to modify the same table you can do this :

```
IF numberOfRow > 0 THEN
          SET NEW.name = "whatever you want it to equal";
        END IF;
```

Comment: I have a similiar of this  on PHP, but i must run via cronjob, i want automatically every time a new record its inserted.

Comment: My bad, you are right , i misread your question. You should use trigger, depending of when you decide, trigger execute query automatically. 
`CREATE TRIGGER table_2_insert 
    AFTER INSERT ON table_2
    FOR EACH ROW     
    UPDATE table_2 set row = value where id IN (select id from table_1)`
I'm not sure about the perfect syntax in this )case, you can check in the Mysql Manuel [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html)

Comment: I did the best I can but I dont have mysql install on my computer to test it .

Comment: I have this erro, with @Matriac example, and the row is not updated.insert into table TABLE_2 failed with 'HY000: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1442 Can't update table 'TABLE2_tweets' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.'

Comment: Oh my bad, you are right , you cant modify the same table that is use in the trigger statement. Its my error sorry Im correcting it in few secondes.

Answer (score 1):

With Matriac example i found this solution:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `TEST`
BEFORE INSERT ON `table2`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
SET NEW.row = (SELECT row_from_table_1 FROM table_1 WHERE id = NEW.id);
END
```